# Problem with multiple instances of a function

Tags: java, oop

I have made a music quiz similar to the one in the iPod, everything runs perfect until my program calls a class MP3 ( http://pastebin.com/d52fe24ce ) to stop with the function close(). The problem in my case is that the MP3 is not "instantiated" when it is called. I am not sure but I think this is because the player I created is not null (see Main.java http://pastebin.com/d32ef2c06 around row 261), although there is actually no "instance" of the player... Anyone have any idea how I can make the player close the stream?

Comment: Aside from wild guesses and vague generalizations, nobody's going to be able to do much for you here unless you post some code. Also, if you suspect that an object you've created might be null, that's a pretty easy thing to check, right?

Comment: +1 for using pastebin instead of dumping the whole code here

Comment: hey, is the block inside player != null executed or not? would be helpful to know that.

Comment: The block is executed, when I tried to execute it without a running player it gave me NullPointerException.

Comment: Java doesn't have functions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 283, you say:

```
 MP3 player = new MP3...
```

Here, you create a new local variable. Remove the first "MP3" so the new player gets assigned to the field `player`:

```
player = new MP3...
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 283:

```
MP3 player = new MP3(((SongQuestion)question).getSongPath());
```

should be:

```
player = new MP3(((SongQuestion)question).getSongPath());
```

This uses the instance level MP3 player.  What you are doing now creates a new *local* `MP3 player` that masks the instance level one.

Comment: This is what I suspected but didn't know how to actually point the problem out! Thanks, I'll try it!